# Ubuntu ignoring mice

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse, touchpad, xinput

I have this issue in Ubuntu 20.04 (running under KDE desktop).

Whenever I plug a mouse to my computer, it does detect it, it appears on my xinput list, but it never works. OS keeps ignoring it. My xinput list would be like this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:3045 Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver Consumer Control      id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver                       id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver System Control        id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver Consumer Control      id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This happens whether the mouse is wireless or not, as I've already tried with a few different mice.

If I go to "Ignored devices" list in the "Enable/Disable M Touchpad" tab under "Touchpad -System Settings Module", my mouse appears there, but I find no way of remove it from that list. If I check the "Disable touchpad when mouse is plugged in" I just lose control over my touchpad and I have to enable it back from command line, but mouse does not work anyway.

I've been looking for some solution for a while and tried a few, but none of them seemed to address exactly the same problem and none of them worked for me.

What is your guess is the source of my problem here? How I can tell the system to stop ignoring pointers others than my touchpad?